# how to use sessionStorage.clear() in other component?

Tags: angular, session-storage

I use Angular 4 and fill some filter data in my `sessionStorage` in my project component to store them during my browser session. I have also another component named navbar with methods like `logout()`.
Now I want to clear my filter out of the `sessionStorage` if I click on `logout()`.

I tried this in my `navBar` Component:

```js
logout (): void {
  sessionStorage.clear();
}
```

I also tried to implement this in my `projectComponent`:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
...
public deleteFilter(){
  sessionStorage.clear();
}
```

And put this in the `navbarComponent` Constructor:

```js
private project: Projects;
```

and use in my `navbarComponent` logout method a function call to let the project delete the session items.

```js
logout (): void {
  this.project.deleteFilter();
}
```

But if I logout and login the filter are still stored.
I can delete them directly in my browser with pressing f12 => "Application" => "clear Storage"

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Just for your best! Use Angular latest (12 at the moment), 4 is deprecated!

Comment: I wish I could do it, but this is a very old project with a lot of dependencies and I can't update it to the newest. I tried once and everything crashed. So it will be a future task If I have more time for refactoring and updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create an [Angular service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4),

The service looks like this

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
  constructor() {}

  public clear() {
    sessionStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

Usage #1

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'usage1',
  templateUrl: './usage1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usage1.component.css']
})
export class Usage1Component {
  constructor(private storageService: StorageService) {
    // You can use the method like this
    this.storageService.clear();
  }
}
```

Usage #2

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'usage2',
  templateUrl: './usage2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usage2.component.css']
})
export class Usage2Component {
  @Input() name: string;
  constructor(private storageService: StorageService) {
    // You can use the method like this
    this.storageService.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I will try it with a service. Unfortunally I can't upvote your answer, because I have a new account with not enough points.

Comment: I tried to do it like your code, but It doesnt work for me. Is **usage1** my _projectComponent_ and **usage2** the _navbarComponent_?

Comment: Try to call your function before the logout function calls

Comment: Also the session storage only applies to a single browser window

Comment: Your'e right, I tried ``console.log("test);`` in my logout method and it doesn't works. I think I have some problems to call this method. I will try and test some things but thank you for your help. I'm sure this service will work.

Comment: If you need it in all browser windows use local storage instead